# UseEffect called when check box is checked inside a nested flatlist

Tags: json, react-native, react-hooks

so I'm working with a deeply nested JSON data where there are multiple checkboxes involved .So whenever I check a checkbox the use effect gets called which I don't think is the correct behavior

UseEffect function 
im passing the nested json to the dependency array since when there are modifications deep in the tree use effect should get called ,but it gets called on every check and uncheck of a checkbox

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in");
  }, [...fetchedData.map((item) => item.orderList.map((item) => item.orders))]);
```

checkbox click handler

```
  const checkboxHandler = useCallback((orderId, subId, id) => {
    const x = orderId + "-" + subId + "-" + id;
    if (checkedArr.indexOf(x) > -1) {
      let filteredArray = checkedArr.filter((item) => item !== x);
      setcheckedArr(filteredArray);
    } else {
      setcheckedArr([...checkedArr, x]);
    }
  }, []);
```

So I'm a beginner to react native ,so wanted to know what I'm doing wrong also another question would be am I rendering he flatlist in a efficient way for nested json .

[Please find the snack link to test/play around](https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/grounded-soylent)

Any help or suggestions are welcome thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the spread operator in the dependency array, it will rerender everytime the state is updated, in your case, it should be completely fine to leave it like this:

```
useEffect(() => { console.log("in"); }, [fetchedData]);
```

unless you need to check specific elements, and in this case do the filters in another hook `useMemo` .

Comment: Understood ,i need to check for specific element change the elements are deep inside the nested JSON  ,any example i can refer for use Memo for my case ?

Comment: could be something like this 
const orders = useMemo(fetchedData.map((item) => item.orderList.map((item) => item.orders)), [fetchedData]) 
then replace it in the dependencies array

Comment: React compares data referentially. For primitive types it is essentially the same as doing a real comparison; but for objects, it means that a change wont be detected until the state references changes. This why when setting state it is recommend to set it to a new array, or a new object.

Comment: With that in mind, I imagine that you wont be able to get an `useEffect` to run only when a specific nested property change, because whenever that property's siblings are updated, it too gets updated

Comment: @PhantomSpooks understood, I think that would be a performance impact right  ? As Mustafa khalil suggested best to use useMemo in these situations, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit, I think that the unexpected re-renders would be minimum, if you only deep cloned your object when you absolutely needed to